# If a function $f:J\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the Zygmund condition, is it $C^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

A function $f\colon J\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on an open interval $J$ satisfies *Zygmund* condition if, for all 
$x,y\in J$, $$f(x)+f(y)-2f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)=o(|x-y|).$$ It is clear, if $f\in  C^{1}$, then it satisfies *Zygmund* condition. **Q:** What about the reverse?

Comment: Don't use `$...$` when you want italic text. `$Zygmund$` produces $Zygmund$, which means "the product of the variables $Z$, $y$, $g$, $m$, $u$, $n$, and $d$". Use `*...*` when you want to put *text* in italics. [See here for other markdown formatting commands](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Question. If a function $f:J→R$ satisfies the $Zygmund$ condition, is it $C^1$?

Comment: Yes, that is your question.  And use `*Zygmund*`, not `$Zygmund$`.

Comment: Such a function does not even have to be Lebesgue measurable, as any non-linear additive function suffices to show. The standard reference for topics related to your question is Brian S. Thomson's 1994 book [**Symmetric Properties of Real Functions**](http://www.amazon.ca/dp/0824792300).